# How do you change the look of a check box?

Tags: cocoa

I would like to create a custom check box that functions just like a normal check box but looks different, at the moment I am using normal check box's, is there a way to do this.

P.S This is Cocoa i am talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override NSButtonCell. You'll use `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` or a simililar method to do your custom drawing. If you've never used custom cells before it can be a bit of a learning experience, but there's a lot of good advice out there, like [this page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSButtonCell) to start with.

You could also take a look at an open source framework like [BGHUDAppKit](https://github.com/binarygod/BGHUDAppKit) for an example.

Comment: How do you implement the BGHUDAppKit?

Comment: It's just a standard framework, you can find instructions in the wiki: http://code.google.com/p/bghudappkit/wiki/UsingFramework

Comment: How do you download BGHUDAppKit?

Comment: Open the Terminal and type this "svn checkout http://bghudappkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ bghudappkit-read-only
"
That will download the BGHUDAppKit XCode project and place it in your home directory. You can move it from there to wherever and open in XCode.

Comment: It says that bghudappkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk is not a valid url.

Answer (score 4):

As a sidenote, if the only thing you need to do is change the 'check' image from the default one provided by Apple, then go to the properties of the NSButton in XCode/Interface Builder and select an Image and an Alternate Image. Same thing goes for radio buttons.

Comment: There are two versions of the "alternate Image": The white tick on blue background (when the window has focus -assuming System Preferences set to 'blue' and not 'graphite'), and the black tick on white background (when the window doesn't have focus). Querying the `alternateImage` property and writing the mage to file gives the "active version". How can I set a custom image so that it behaves this way? (black outline vs. blue fill)

Comment: Also -since Yosemite at least- the tick seems to animate into position (by zooming in from "zero size") when checking the checkbox. Doesn't look like there's an easy way to swap the default tick for my custom image, and get all the same effects "for free"...